# PHP mySQL change the quantity for the remaining tickets

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The problem is that i want to change the quantity of the ticket remaining but when i try to submit my input value the code doesn't change the value of mySQL, But at first when the buy button did change the remaining tickets it removed all of them instead of the input value of 1 to 8.

my PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
WinterValley | Tickets
<style>
    <?php include '../style.css'; ?>
</style>
<?php
try {
    // PDO Connection
    $serverName = "localhost";
    $dbname = "wintervalley";
    $dBUsername = "root";
    $dBPassword = "";
    $charset = 'utf8mb4';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$serverName;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

// Table connection
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tickets_finland`");
$stmt->execute();
$tickets_finland_data = $stmt->fetchAll();
$total_tickets_finland = $stmt->fetchColumn();

// Database ticket_pop-up content
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['ticketQuantity_finland'])) {
        $ticketQuantity_finland = $_POST['ticketQuantity_finland'];
        if (is_numeric($ticketQuantity_finland) && $ticketQuantity_finland >= 1 && $ticketQuantity_finland <= 8) {
            // Retrieve current quantity
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT quantity FROM `tickets_finland` WHERE id = :id");
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $tickets_finland_data[0]['id']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $total_tickets_finland = $stmt->fetchColumn();

            // Update the quantity
            $new_total_tickets = $total_tickets_finland - $ticketQuantity_finland;
            if ($new_total_tickets >= 0) {
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tickets_finland SET quantity = :new_total_tickets WHERE id = :id");
                $stmt->bindParam(':new_total_tickets', $new_total_tickets);
                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $tickets_finland_data[0]['id']);
                $stmt->execute();
            } else {
                echo "Invalid input: Not enough tickets available";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Invalid input: Enter a number between 1 and 8";
        }
    }
}
?>
<!-- logo -->

<a href="index.php"> <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
<h1>WinterValley</h1>

<!--login/register -->
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION["useruid"])) {
    echo '<a class="log-out-button" href="../include/logout.inc.php">Log out</a>';
} else {
    include "../include/login.php";
?> <div class="empty2"></div> <?php
                                        include "../include/register.php";
                                    }
                                        ?>
<div class="empty3"></div>
</div>
<!-- navbar -->
<?php include "../include/navbar.php" ?>

<!-- Ticket pop-ups -->
<!-- Ticket pop-up (Finland) -->
<div class="ticketPopupBox">
    <div class="ticketPopup" id="ticket_pop-up_finland">
        <form class="ticketContainer">
            <label for="ticketCheckbox">
                <h2 class="popup_ticket_title">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($tickets_finland_data as $ticket_fi) {
                        echo $ticket_fi['event_id'] . "<br>";
                    }
                    ?></h2>
            </label>
            <div class="checkbox_info">
                <?php
                foreach ($tickets_finland_data as $ticket_fi) {
                    echo "€" . $ticket_fi['ticket_price'] . "<br>";
                }
                ?>
                <form method="post" action="../page/tickets.php">
                    <label for="ticketQuantity">Number of tickets:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="ticketQuantity_finland" name="ticketQuantity_finland" min="1" max="8" required>
                    <input type="submit" value="Buy" class="btnTicket">
                </form>
                <?php
                foreach ($tickets_finland_data as $ticket_fi) {
                    echo $ticket_fi['quantity'] . " Remaining" . "<br>";
                }
                ?>
                <div class="ticket_featuring">
                    <p>Featuring:</p>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Sarah Brightman</li>
                        <li>Ed Sheeran</li>
                        <li>Kate Bush</li>
                        <li>Linkin Park</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn_cancelTicket" onclick="ticket_closePopupFinland()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Ticket info -->
<div class="ticket_box">
    <h1 class="ticket_h1">Tickets for Upcoming Events</h1>
    <div class="ticket_afstand">

        <div class="finland_bg">
            <div class="ticket_content">
                <h2 class="ticket_head">WinterValley Finland</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>16:00-00:00</li>
                    <li>25th February 2023</li>
                    <li>Eerikinkatu 3, 00100 Helsinki</li>
                    <div><button onclick="ticket_openPopupFinland()" class="ticket_button">Buy now</button></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include "../include/footer.php" ?>

<script>
        // functie pop-up Finland
        function ticket_openPopupFinland() {
        document.getElementById("ticket_pop-up_finland").style.display = "block";
    }

    function ticket_closePopupFinland() {
        document.getElementById("ticket_pop-up_finland").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

mySQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets_finland` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `event_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL CHECK (`quantity` \<= 2000), 
    `ticket_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

What i want is that if you input a value between 1 to 8 it removes that value from the database.

Comment: Do you have separate tickets tables for each country? Consider one common tickets table instead, with a country column.

Comment: Yes, i have 3 tables for each country.  im new to sql and thought that it was a better way to do it. so now do i make one table with an id, country_name, quantity, price?

Comment: Yes, that's a better approach. (If you want, you can also create a view that returns the Finland rows only.)

Comment: You cannot do a `$stmt->fetchColumn();` after a `->fetchAll()` the fetchAll will have consumed all the resultset so there is nothing more for the fetchColumn()` to access

Comment: Much simpler query would be `UPDATE tickets_finland SET quantity = quantity - :tickets WHERE id = :id` and use `$ticketQuantity_finland` to bind to `:tickets`